# Animation delay CSS3 before & after with infinite loop

Tags: css, animation, delay, infinite

I tried a lot of CSS tricks but it looks like nothing is working as expected. 
I want to manage the `animation-delays` before and after for playing with infinite loop.

The goal is to animate the whole content under a 4/5s animation duration and apply an infinite loop.

Here is the current code from the SVG. To animate the content i was obliged to integrate a `<style>` directly into the `<svg>` :

[jsfiddle.net/9bpyewsg](http://jsfiddle.net/9bpyewsg)

Below an example of the complex animation :

```
/* mixer */
  .mixermove {animation: mixermove .75s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) both;}
    @keyframes mixermove {
      0% {opacity:0; transform: translate(108.659574px,500px);}
        100% {opacity:1; transform: translate(108.659574, 64.510638);}
  }

  /* mixer reflection */
  .mixerRmove {animation: 1s mixerRmove both;}
    @keyframes mixerRmove {
      0% {opacity:0; transform: translate(105.977801px,200px);}
        100% {opacity:.25;transform: translate(105.977801, 250.377654);}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, Not sure if this helps. You can use jquery's event `oAnimationStart` and `oAnimationEnd`

```
$('.element').one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
    // what needs to be done
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, we have to play with the `%` and `keyframes` :

```
.redmove {animation: 5s redmove ease-in infinite;}
@keyframes redmove {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0.510638px, 90.531915px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0.510638px, 90.531915px);
  }
}
```

The first 0 to 30% is the animation and the 30 to 100% is the "second" animation and in this case the block stays at its own position.